# Representing multisets

Tags: category-theory, multisets

Multisets are like sets, but the "elements" can have multiplicities.  An example is $M = \{ a,a, a, b,c,b,c \}$.  We can present the multiset by giving the multiplicities for each set element.  Can we represent the multiset with just a function?  Say your symbol set is $A$, and you have an "indexing set" $C$ and a function $f: C \rightarrow A$.  Then the multiplicity of element $a \in A$ is the cardinality of the preimage of $f$ at element $a$.  Thus a category of multisets can have functions as objects.

Comment: Yea, multisets are usually defined as functions from an indexed set to the universe of all possible elements.

Comment: I would add the condition that $f$ should be surjective.